# is there @protected method?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to declare a method in a BaseObject, and this method only implemented by the SubObject, how can I do that? I found  @protected is permitted to be used on method.

Comment: One approach is to put a class extension ( i.e `@interface TheClass () ... @end` ) in which the "protected" method is declared in a second header file ( `TheClass_SubclassInterface.h` ) and import that second header into the class' implementation file ( `TheClass.m` ) and into any subclass implementation file ( `TheSubclass.m` where `TheSubclass : TheClass` ) in which you need to use the "protected" method.

Comment: See the docs for `UIGestureRecognizer`. There is a section labeled "Subclassing Notes". This is an example of what Nate is referring to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way around this is to create a private header file containing a private interface category, like this:

```
//MyClass.h

@interface MyClass : NSObject

- (void)publicMethod;

@end

//MyClass_private.h

@interface MyClass ()

- (void)protectedMethod;

@end
```

MyClass.m and it's subclasses import the regular and _private headers, giving the _private declarations the same scope as protected.  Customers of the hierarchy use only the regular headers.

Answer (score 4):

No protected is only allowed for variables not methods

Comment: I know that, what I want to know is that is there any way to make it like protected method.

Answer (score -1):

Protected methods are not explicitly supported by objective-c.

In order to simulate a protected method I simply do not include the function definition in the header file.  This allows sub-classes to implement the method and does not allow that method to be called externally (aka. "protected").

Comment: This doesn't work if the implementation of the method in the subclass needs to call the implementation in the base class.

Comment: Brandon, I _believe_ what you are describing is a "private" method, since it can not be called even by derived classes.